# Автоматизированная отправка сообщений в чаты Telegram на Python

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Сделал из своего клиента посредствам библиотеки *telethon* бота. Увидел в документации, что можно отправлять сообщения людям по нику и номеру телефона, а также в чаты, зная их айди. Мне же, нужно постить сообщение НЕ в свой чат. Айди чужого чата ведь нельзя узнать, тогда как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Айди чужого чата узнать можно, для тебя скорее всего это **message.chat.id**.
А вообще рекомендую использовать асинхронный фреймворк https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram

Answer (score 0):

Если ты находишься в этом чате, `id` которого нужно получить, то вот функция которая это будет делать:

```
acync def func_name(event):
     # получаешь данные: человек это, чат или канал
     data = event.message.to_dict()["peer_id"]["_"]
     if data == "PeerChat":
          # получаешь id чата, насчёт синтаксиса не уверен,
          # но суть я думаю ты понял
          uid = event.message.to_dict()["peer_id"]["chat_id"]
```